# Difference between using Map and HashMap as declared type

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

What's the difference between the following two declaration statements:

```
HashMap<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();

Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
```

Any advantages of using the interface `Map` instead of `HashMap` in this particular case?

In the following case, is Map definitely better because the method can accept different types of maps?(if it is intended to)

```
public void method(Map map){

}
```

Comment: The answer to your second question is yes for the reason you stated. The answer to your first question is yes because it enforces the correct behaviour in your second question (you can't write methods which accept `HashMap` then try to pass a `Map`, the compiler won't let you.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no underlying difference. It is more about the interface. There's an advantage of using a `Map` though, that is you can change the object to be a different kind of a `Map` without breaking the contract of the code using it.

The `HashMap` is an implementation of `Map`, which is part of the Java Collections Framework. If you settle on using the `HashMap` and then the other party wishes for something different, like `LinkedHashMap` (preserves iteration order), then you have to change things around. Here's a diagram (courtesy ProgramCreek).

[image]

There are other things like computational time complexity, if you care about performance. Here's a small table that helps. Choosing the right thing is a question of design and need i.e. what are you trying to do. It varies from project to project.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The second version is preferred because if you want to write code later to change `map` to a different kind of `Map`, you will need to use the second version. But it really is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

in the perspective of the object-oriented,During compilation, 
the method is bound reference class type,
so HashMap map = new HashMap();
You can us hashMap methods ,Including the realization map and extended. But ,
Map map = new HashMap(); 
You can only use methods declared in map .Can not used hashMap methods.